# What is the Dos 8.3 filename hash for more than 4 files with the same first 6 characters?

Tags: hash, dos

for example: AB5C8A~1

As I understand the first two characters are from the regular filename. Can someone direct me to the math behind how DOS settles on the third to sixth characters?

Answer (score 2):

from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), there is no compulsory algorithm for creating the 8.3 name from a long file name, but they do *try* to follow a convention. With the file name in your example, it seems to be using option 4 where is uses a hash of the file name to produce 4 hex digits

I have found some code, but I don't know if it is the same as what microsoft use...

from [this site](http://www.rtems.com/) for licence

All *(some?)* source available for their system [here](http://fidelio.qi-hardware.com/~xiangfu/milkymist-firmware/milkymist/rtems/cpukit/libfs/src/)

```
/* msdos_short_hex_number --
 *     Routine to set the hex number in the SFN.
 *
 * PARAMETERS:
 *     name      - name to change
 *     num       - number to set
 *
 * RETURNS:
 *     nothing
 *
 */
static void
msdos_short_name_hex(char* sfn, int num)
{
    static const char* hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char* c = MSDOS_DIR_NAME(sfn);
    int   i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++, c++)
      if ((*c == ' ') || (*c == '.'))
        *c = '_';
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++, c++)
      *c = hex[(num >> ((3 - i) * 4)) & 0xf];
    *c++ = '~';
    *c++ = '1';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering -- my question is exactly about the "hash" you mention. What is the math behind this hash? How does DOS actually calculate those numbers, given the file history and all? The reason I'm asking is to help me understand how to emulate it.

Comment: per the wiki, the calculation is undocumented

Comment: yea, I read that too, but was hoping maybe someone who has deep knowledge of how DOS is built might know.

Comment: found some source from another site that may shed some light. [ymmv](http://www.internetslang.com/YMMV-meaning-definition.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Sean Cheshire provides a good reference in his answer. But the rules are only partially documented.

Even if the full algorithm were documented, I don't see how you could reliably predict the 8.3 name of a given file without knowing the full history of the containing folder. The name assigned can vary depending on how many similarly named files existed in the same folder prior to its creation.

The only reliable method to get the 8.3 name is to query the directory.

The simplest method is to use the `/x` option of the DIR command, but that output is not convenient for parsing.

The easiest method to get the 8.3 name into a variable is to use the `~s` modifier with a FOR variable or CALL parameter.

```
for %%F in ("long file name.ext") do set "shortName=%~sF"
```

or

```
call :getShort "long file name.ext"
exit /b

:getShort
set "shortName=%~s1"
exit /b
```

Note - it is much faster to use FOR instead of CALL

The 8.3 name is also available via the WMIC DATAFILE alias.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering -- my question, though, is about the math behind this hash. How does DOS actually calculate those numbers, given the file history and all? The reason I'm asking is to help me understand how to emulate it.

Comment: @alhambra - Why do you want to emulate it? It sounds to me like you want to predict the short name based on the long name. As I tried to explain, that cannot be done without the complete file history for the folder. By history I mean every file creation, rename, or deletion in the folder, and when that event occurred. I don't think that level of history is maintained by Windows. So knowing the hash algorithm most likely does you no good.

Comment: I want to predict the short name based on the complete file history in my own emulation of a DOS prompt. I also became more curious about the hash after observing some of the patterns it creates in relation to filenames.